# Getting RSS from website

Tags: ios, objective-c, rss

I'm trying to get the **RSS feeds** from this page: `http://sports.espn.go.com/espn/news/story?page=rssinfo`

It lists a bunch, but if I click on the links it asks me to open them in a RSS Reader app.

I just **want to use them to put in my app** like such: 
    `NSURL *nbaBill = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://search.espn.go.com/rss/bill-simmons/"];`

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: Where exactly do you have a problem?

If you just need a tutorial for downloading / parsing rss feeds take a look at this one:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/2636/rss-reader-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-make-a-simple-rss-reader-iphone-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app is parsing RSS feeds to display content, then there's nothing wrong with the line that you're using at the moment. If you want to view the XML content to work on your code, depending on your browser you should select `to view page source` after opening the link.

For example in Google Chrome, open the feed link, then right click anywhere in the page and select `View Page Source`. This will open you a page with the URL:

```
view-source:http://search.espn.go.com/rss/bill-simmons/
```

Which shows you the raw XML format of the file.